# A "nice" trigonometric polynomial approximation of a characteristic function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis

Let $\delta > 0$ be small and $\chi_{[-\delta, \delta]}(t)$ be a characteristic function on the interval $[-\delta, \delta]$. I am interested in a trigonometric polynomial $S$ such that
$$
\chi_{[-\delta, \delta]}(t) \leq S(t)
$$
such that and $S(t) = 0$ if $|t| > 2 \delta$ with some control on the coefficients of $S$. I apologize that the question is rather vague but I am looking for a place to start looking into something like this.

I would greatly appreciate any references or comments! Thank you!

Comment: The in-some-ways optimal trig poly for this is called Selberg's "Magic" polynomial. They're in chapter 1 of Montgomery's "10 Lectures on the Interface". Iirc, Jeffrey Vaaler has written about them recently.

Comment: If S(t)=0 for $|t|>2\delta$, it is not a trigonometric polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick any $f$ that bounds above the characteristic function of $[-\delta, \delta]$. For example the sine kernel $(\frac{\sin x}{x})^2$ or a higher power conveniently rescaled to fit your requirements. Then make your upper bound $f(t)$ periodic by considering $F(t) = \sum_{n} f(t + n)$. Then make sure that your $f$ has the property that $\widehat{f}$ is compactly supported (this is guaranteed by Paley Wiener if $f$ is analytic and has no more than exponential growth in the complex plane). Then apply Poisson summation to see that $F(t) = \sum_{n} \widehat{f}(n) e^{2\pi i t n}$ is in fact your desired trigonometric polynomial.

Comment: By the way as has been pointed out you cannot have $S(t) = 0$ for a trigonometric polynomial on any open interval, as that implies $S \equiv 0$ because $S$ is analytic.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! By the way can we at least say that the function constructed here is small outside $[-\delta, \delta]$?

Comment: Yes because you get to specify the $f(t)$ and then your function is $F(t) = \sum_{n} f(t + n)$ so you can directly check how small it is . Note that it so happens that when $f$ is analytic with $f(z) = O(e^{c |z|})$ for some $c > 0$ that $F(t)$ is also a trigonometric polynomial with coefficients $\widehat{f}(n)$ (so you can also compute them with a bit of effort!) . An easy choice for $f$ is $f(t) = (\sin t / t)^{A}$ conveniently rescaled and with some convenient $A$. The higher the $A$ the more concentrated your $F$ will be (however the coefficients $\widehat{f}(n)$ will be more spread out).